# How can I mix two formula in excel?

Tags: excel

How could I create from these two formulas only one?

C2 is the following in the first formula:

```
=LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(CSVimport.I2;" ";"-");"->";"/");"|";"/"))
```

2nd formula:
=LEFT(C2;LEN(C2)-FIND("/";C2)+1)

Both formula should work on the csvimport.i2 just in one.

Or maybe there is an easier formula to achieve this:
I want from this:

```
Dell Latitude Laptop->Dell Latitude E5570 Laptop|Dell Latitude Laptop
```

to this only:

```
dell-latitude-laptop/dell-latitude-e5570-laptop/
```

With this 2 it works but would be good only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure there is other way than this:

```
=LEFT(LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(CSVimport.I2;" ";"-");"->";"/");"|";"/"));LEN(LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(CSVimport.I2;" ";"-");"->";"/");"|";"/")))-FIND("/";LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(CSVimport.I2;" ";"-");"->";"/");"|";"/")))+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly shorter:

```
=LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(CSVimport.I2;FIND("|";CSVimport.I2)-1);"->";"/");" ";"-") & "/")
```

[image: ![enter image description here]